# undefined method `execute_script' in page object gem

Tags: ruby, page-object-gem

I have started to get this error when running my tests using the 1.2.2 version of the page object gem

**Stacktrace**

```
undefined method `execute_script' for <Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Bridge:0x00000003cbdba0> (NoMethodError)

/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/page-object-1.2.2/lib/page-object/platforms/selenium_webdriver/element.rb:146:in `parent'

/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/page-object-1.2.2/lib/page-object/platforms/selenium_webdriver/table_row.rb:30:in `find_index_by_title'

/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/page-object-1.2.2/lib/page-object/platforms/selenium_webdriver/table_row.rb:15:in `[]'
```

It occurs when trying to get the value from a table using a method such as

```
left_table_element[rank][column]
```

**NB.** This had been previously working for over a year so I wonder if a new issue has been introduced?

Looking at the git blame it does seem like the line of code throwing the error in the element.rb might have been changed recently and maybe caused this regression?

Comment: have you recently updated FireFox? If yes, try downgrading it to an earlier version: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/install-older-version-of-firefox

Answer (score 1):

The problem is due a change in Selenium-WebDriver. In version 3.0.0, the `Remote::Bridge#executeScript` method was renamed to `#execute_script`.

The Page-Object gem was updated in version 1.2.2 to use the new method. However, the gem dependencies were not updated to reflect the required version - ie Selenium-WebDriver v2.53.4 is still listed as the minimum requirement. It looks like this has already been fixed in the eventual Page-Object v2.0 release.

In the meantime, you can fix the issue by upgrading to Selenium-WebDriver v3 (assuming you do not want to downgrade Page-Object):

```
gem install selenium-webdriver
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue just need to update your page-object gem to 1.2.2 version

gem install -v 1.2.2 (for selenium-webdriver 3.x only)